# Google WMT Site Performance not updating

Tags: google-search-console

The Google WMT tool for "site performance" hasn't updated in 3 weeks for me. I'm getting enough traffic to the site and google crawls a few thousand pages a day on average.
Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine has not updated for 3 weeks either. I've had the same issue before - the updates can be rather sporadic.

Actually, [Google announced back in April](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/webmaster-tools-spring-cleaning.html) that the Site Performance feature would be removed (within two weeks of the publish date) due to low usage. So I wouldn't count on the feature sticking around. As the above article states, Google Analytics can track site speed times.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about that announcement. I liked the WMT version since it showed "faster than xx% of sites"

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting enough traffic

But you might not be getting the right kind of traffic. From [Webmaster Tools Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158541#2):

> Data may also not be available for your site if not enough users (with
>   **Google Toolbar and the PageRank feature turned on**) have visited your
>   site's pages during the time period displayed.

So, your "site performance" is only measured by users that have Google Toolbar with the optional PageRank feature enabled! I imagine this could be a very small percentage of your overall traffic. In my opinion the PageRank feature is something that only developers have enabled (this is a specific opt-in feature since it discloses all the URLs you visit to Google) so whether the "site performance" tool works at all for your site could even be dependent on your sites subject matter?! Is it a technical site that other developers visit?

Comment: that makes sense. However it shows "These estimates are of high accuracy (more than 1000 data points)" and most visitors to the site are regulars. So I don't think that suddenly they stopped using the Toolbar with the PageRank feature

Comment: The frequency with which the site performance graph updates certainly does seem to vary (possibly related to traffic volume) and there have been [quite a few reports](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/v7h7_lqTBgk) of this apparently stalling for periods of time (perhaps even through a change at Google's end, or through changes in a sites traffic). I'm not sure what the resolution of this is, other than time? A delay of several weeks does not appear to be that uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

Google will crawl the Pages according to which we have set the Frequency to Google Crawl the Pages.(Like Daily, Weekly, Monthly). So You can re upload Site map.XML ans set the frequency for daily.

Comment: It is already stated in the question... "google crawls a few thousand pages a day". But that is not the question being asked.